# Client Modules (DTOs) as a Multi-module or Separate Project Repo

Tags: spring-boot, dto

Our project team had adopted Client Modules as a way to share DTOs with other Micro-Services (references: https://www.vinsguru.com/microservices-architecture-how-to-share-dto-data-transfer-objects/ and https://www.baeldung.com/java-microservices-share-dto).
However, 1 question that we had in mind was whether to structure the client modules (DTOs) within the Microservice as a multi-module project, or to locate it separately in a different project repo.

In this case, we envision the client-module to be uploaded onto our internal Maven Repository, while the Microservice will be deployed in our Kubernetes clusters.

As such, would like to seek opinion on:

1. how would you structure your Spring Boot projects if you adopted Client Module to share DTOs and
2. the pros and cons to structuring the client modules (DTOs) in a multi-module project within the Microservice, or to locate it separately in a different project repo.

Feel free to comment if you have any questions. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

Some of the enterprise projects that I worked on used multi module approaches to separate client and microservice modules. The broad idea is as follows.

1. Have 3 modules: Client, Integration testing and microservice.
2. In the client module, place all resources you wish to share with others: DTOs, exception, Feign managers, and enums etc. Package this module as a Jar
3. Place all service and data layer logic in the micro service modules. This module will be packaged as a boot jar which can be deployed to your targets.
4. Place integration tests in the integration testing modules. The packaging is optional here.

The pros of this approach is as follows:

1. There is clear separation of concern between client, service and testing modules.
2. There is a very tight security: you won't be exposing your service logic unless you would want to.

The cons(Purely my opinion):

1. Managing the artifacts is cumbersome.